# Solving overlapping scales on Y-axis in R plot.

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting this graph below:

[image: Graph]

Using this data-

Dput:

```
structure(list(trap = structure(1:9, .Label = c("12:00-18:00", 
"18:00-20:00", "20:00-22:00", "22:00-24:00", "24:00-02:00", "02:00-04:00", 
"04:00-06:00", "06:00-12:00", "08:00"), class = "factor"), gambiae = c(26L, 
32L, 40L, 45L, 27L, 8L, 14L, 6L, NA), funestus = c(6L, 15L, 11L, 
11L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA), bed = c(0, 0, 0.073458921, 0.57100855, 
0.927149125, 0.969466875, 0.794791474, 0.099302825, 0)), .Names = c("trap", 
"gambiae", "funestus", "bed"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is my code for the graph:

```
par(mar = c(6,6,2,5))
with(bedtimes, plot(as.numeric(trap), gambiae, type="l", col="red3", 
                    ylab=expression(italic(p))), 
     ylim=c(0,40))  
par(new = T)
with(bedtimes, plot(as.numeric(trap), bed, type="l", axes=F, xlab="Time", ylab=NA, cex=1.2))
axis(4)
axis(side = 1, las=2, at=1:length(levels(bedtimes$trap)), levels(bedtimes$trap))
mtext(side = 4, line = 3, 'Proportion in bed')
polygon(bedtimes$bed,col=transp("gray"), border = NA)
par(new=T)
with(bedtimes, plot(as.numeric(trap), funestus, type="l", col="blue3", 
                    ylab=expression(italic(p))), 
     ylim=c(0,40))
```

The maximum value of the red line is 40, and the maximum value of the blue line is 15. But as you can see in the graph the two scales are overlapping. What I need is for the y-axis to be plotted from 0-40 and the lines to be plotted according to this range.

I thought that using ylim=c(0,40)) would set the y axis range but this hasn't worked for me. How do I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the `ylim` argument inside the `plot` function.

```
with(bedtimes, plot(as.numeric(trap), funestus, type="l", col="blue3", 
                    ylab=expression(italic(p)),ylim=c(0,40)))
```

---

Also, the maximum value for the red line is actually 45. Change `ylim` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait at lest 10 minutes before you can accept an answer.